# Website Login/Logout time captured and recorded in excel

Tags: vba, excel, web, web-scraping

**Is it possible to record time changes on website?**

What I mean is, in our office, we have an "intranet website" that we use to login and logout. I want to record the changes on the website so that I can track the time that I'm logged in and logged out as it is the basis on how we could get paid.

Once I gather the time data, I would be able to create a table that I will use to add the time that I'm logged in.

Comment: I think you can add extra feild (timestamp) while login (session creation) and log out (session destroy)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Do you have specific code that can gather the time and write it in excel whenever the login button is clicked for example?

Answer (score 0):

Recording when somebody logs in is relatively easy. Details depend on the platform/CMS your intranet site runs on. This gets more complicated quickly,e.g. when people get logged out automatically after a certain period of inactivity (but are still at their workplaces), or re-login at +- the same time from a differnent device. ("Hm, PC login shows spinnner icon, lets try iPad too..."), or when they forget to log-out.

To make this more robust, I would record the login times to a database such as MS SQL Server, Access, or similar and then import into Excel from there (via ODBC connection), or via periodic exports ("dumps") into Excel files.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Do you have specific code that can gather the time and write it in excel whenever the login button is clicked for example?